# "Illegal Argument - invalid copyarea root path" while trying to create view in ClearCase Remote Client

Tags: clearcase-remote-client

$subj error appears after pressing "*Finish*" on new view creation dialog. The path looks absolutely valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is caused by `.copyarea.dat` (and perhaps `.copyarea.db`) files on the same or higher directory level where you want to create the view. It looks like a protection from nested views, but if you created the file in your `$HOME` (accidentally, or for backup purposes), you're out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create a CCRC view in `$HOME`:

As mentioned in "[About the CCRC .ccase_wvreg file](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?&rs=984&uid=swg21228258)":

> ClearCase Remote Client creates and stores a file local to each CCRC client named **`.ccase_wvreg`** (web view registry) in the user's home directory.
>   When the first view is created using CCRC, this file stores the local path to the view root (copy area) for each CCRC view on the system for a given user.

So trying to create a view, which would contain the "view registry" of *all* your view is... not possible.

> After creation of a view from CCRC, the `.ccase_wvreg` file is stored under:
>
> - On Windows:
>     `C:\Documents and Settings\<username>` where `<username>` is the actual user name who created the view or the path that is extrapolated from the environment variable `%USERPROFILE%` (this path may be local or remote).
> - On UNIX/Linux:
>     `/export/home/<username>`, which is the user's home directory that created the view or the path as indicated by cd’ing to `~<username>`.

Comment: Sure, you **can** create `$HOME/<view name>` unless there is `.copyarea.dat` in your `$HOME`. But I guess you meant `$HOME == <absolute view path>`. No, I didn't try that. I simply copied `.copyarea.dat` to `$HOME` temporarily while trying to find a workaround to one of numerous CCRC limitations, (which deserves its own question, so no details here).